# Spring: Dynamic Naming via Property File / Environment Variable

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, properties

For one of our web application, we use dynamic loading of properties files based on environment in tomcat.

In tomcat we set the environment variable **-Dcustom.env.name="production"** and thus based on the environment the corresponding properties files get picked up and loaded via Spring's PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.

```
 <bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
      <list>
        <value>classpath:jdbc_${custom.env.name}.properties</value>
        <value>classpath:configuration_${custom.env.name}.properties</value>
      </list>
    </property>
 </bean>
```

Now for some reason, we want to have the **custom.env.name** property to be specified via another property file residing on filesystem, outside of the war file. What is the way to achieve this with least code changes.

Answer (score 0):

Use `catalina.properties` to read this property.